# How do I eliminate a green line at the top of my screen?

Tags: wireless, screen, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 2420/2520 and when I update the drivers, a green line appears at the top of the screen. Any idea on how to get rid of that?

Also, how do I get my wireless internet to work?

Comment: Yeah @student ... It is simple indeed: purchase a new screen for your laptop and you're done. Green lines appears randomly and suddenly when the LCD is having a failure, probably a death pixel or copper line in the LCD is broken. You should check if the same problem occurs in a different OS, this will only happen in graphics mode. Text mode (BIOS) won't reproduce the error. Oh! BTW: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Good luck!

Comment: For your wireless related issue I suggest you to open a different question, nevertheless you should first check if some previous answers seems to provide a solution for you, otherwise your new question may be closed because of duplicated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Same here ... brand new Vostro 2420, after installing initial updates and rebooting there are green flashing lines on top of the screen. So something messed up with the graphics driver. No issue when working in text mode or booting of recovery media.

Instead of fixing 11.10 installation, I simply upgraded to 12.10, everything is now working fine.